# How to limit the number of devices that can connect to my TP Link WR740N?

Tags: router, wifi-configuration

I have a wifi router TP Link model number WR740N. I connect phones, computers etc. in my home. I am wondering, is there any option available for this wifi router which can limit the number of devices connecting to it. So if there are 3 devices already connected to the router, then I want no other device can connect to it even it knows the password. How is it possible?

Comment: Well what if another device which knows your password connects before you connect your third device ? Wouldn't improving your router's wifi's security protocols be a better option? ( just suggesting)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just define LAN IP address range for 3 devices in router.
Start IP address : 192.168.1.2
End IP address : 192.168.1.4

In this way only 3 devices will get IP address and will able to access network.

Comment: More over you can define allowed Mac address list for your devices. In this case, if someone knows your password, still they won't be able to connect to router

Comment: ok that's great but can you please tell me where this option is found in tplink settings?

Comment: Which model do you have?

Comment: model number WR740N

Comment: I just checked the manual of your router. It doesn't have exact settings. But still you can use another trick. Refer to official manual from tplink site for your router. Page number number 31 and topic is 4.5.3 LAN. Here define the subnet mask as 255.255.255.251 .. This should work for you. For Mac filtering, refer to page number 37 and topic number 4.6.3.  Here is the link to official manual : http://www.tp-link.com/res/down/doc/TL-WR740N_V6_User_Guide.pdf

Comment: I went through with the manual; actually i already had it. But your two ways confused me a bit. Are both methods dependent on each other? What method should i need to follow?

Comment: Use the subnet method . it is more than enough

Comment: ok. So just defining subnet mask as 255.255.255.251 will do the job? Does this option exist in Network -> LAN?

Comment: Yes. It should work . as per manual, this setting exist in Lan  settings.